# Выбор времени глагола в придаточном с "чтобы"

Tags: синтаксис

> Потребуем, чтобы все веса рёбер графа **были** различны.

1. В какой форме здесь стоит глагол **были** -- сослагательное наклонение или прошедшее время изъявительного наклонения?
2. Вообще, каким правилом регулируется, что я должен поставить глагол **быть** именно в эту форму, а не, например, в форму настоящего времени?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Потребуем, чтобы все веса рёбер графа были различны.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным, для связи используется союз ЧТОБЫ. *Были различны* – составное  именное сказуемое, *были* – глагол- связка в форме прошедшего времени.

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ

Придаточные с союзом   ЧТОБЫ обозначают **ирреальную модальность**, которую  выражает частица БЫ **в составе союза** и форма прошедшего времени  с суффиксом -Л для глагола.

Таким образом,  форма построения изъяснительного  придаточного **соответствует**  форме сослагательного  наклонения (частица БЫ в составе союза и форма прошедшего времени для глагола).

**Сослагательное наклонение**  обозначает возможное, желательное или необходимое действие, но при этом  действие это еще не осуществилось.  **Категория времени** (настоящее, прошедшее, будущее) есть только у **изъявительного** наклонения, к сослагательному и повелительному наклонению категория времени не относится. Сослагательное наклонение **образуется** присоединением к форме прошедшего времени глагола частицы БЫ: *прочитал бы, научил бы.*

Примеры: *Поехать бы домой! Другой на моем месте поступил бы разумнее. Если бы мы поторопились, то успели бы на поезд.*

Ответ на вопрос

1. Глагол ***были*** имеет только  форму, а не значение прошедшего времени.  Глагол выражает значение **ирреальной модальности**, то есть соответствует сослагательному наклонению, но при этом частица  БЫ занимает не свободную позицию, а входит в состав союза.
2. Правило как раз и заключается  **в особом построении  СПП с придаточными изъяснительными с союзом ЧТОБЫ**: частица БЫ в составе союза и форма прошедшего времени для глагола.

Comment: Это же придаточное изъяснительное, а вы, возможно,  говорите об изъявительном наклонении?

Comment: Я излагаю материал по учебнику Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка", но там не говорится, что глагол имеет сослагательное наклонение (ведь частица БЫ не свободная, она входит в союз ЧТОБЫ).

Comment: Я говорю о **сослагательном** наклонении. О котором спрашивает автор вопроса.

Comment: Хотя... Ладно, снимаю пока. мы так аскера запутаем академическими заморочками.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения грамматики тут всё очень просто. Это сослагательное наклонение, а оно требует использования той же глагольной формы, какая используется в прошедшем времени. И это не только в отношении глагола "быть". Небольшая особенность в том, что частица "бы", используемая для сослагательного наклонения, слилась с союзом "что". Нечто подобное наблюдается и с другими частицами, союзами и союзными словами - *дабы, как бы, лишь бы, если бы*, причем в некоторых случая требует слитного написания. Остальное - уже академический уровень, не буду перегружать ответ.

Сложность, особенно у изучающего русский как иностранный, может возникнуть при рассмотрении семантики разных случаев использования сослагательного наклонения в русском. Обычно рассматриваемая конструкция ("глагол + придаточное с "чтобы"), как и вообще все придаточные условного наклонения, несут целевую, относительную или условную фукнцию: *"я хочу, чтобы настало лето", "потребуем, чтобы он пришел", "если бы я знал, я бы ответил"*. Их и так-то не просто отличить одну от другой даже в контексте, но у вас явно математический текст, и смысл высказывания - постулативний, обычно в семантике бытового языка не используемый. Ваш пример - один из возможных переводов английского "let (them) be", в русском нет специальной формы для дословного перевода. Отсюда и грамматика сослагательного наклонения.

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо за правку! Я отвлекся, сам даже не вычитал, чего наколбасил.